# Change x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good afternoon everyone,

I am having difficulties plotting a time series with ggplot. I have a time series with daily data from 2020-01-30 to 2020-10-22. When I plot the data with the following code, I get an x-axis, which is not at all readable:

```
plot_cases <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x= Date, y= Count)) +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Number of Cases") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 2000)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female, aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female$Sex, group = 1)) +
geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male, aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male$Sex, group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF00FF", "#000FFF"))
```

Therefore, I would like to only have the abbreviation of the months represented such as "Apr", "Jul", "Oct". However, as I use the following code, I don't get any x-axis graduation anymore...

```
plot_cases <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x= Date, y= Count)) +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Number of Cases") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 2000)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(as.Date("2020-01-30"), as.Date("2020-10-22"), by = "month")) +
  geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female, aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female$Sex, group = 1)) +
geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male, aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male$Sex, group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF00FF", "#000FFF"))
```

As one of you a solution to this? I have checked the previous questions about scale_x_discrete
but I still don't get how to do the relevant changes.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This would be far easier if you converted your dates to actual dates or date-time objects. At the moment they must be character strings or factors.

Comment: Assuming that @AllanCameron's comment is true (I agree), then you will likely need `as.Date` (or `as.POSIXct`) and then use `ggplot2::scale_x_date` to format it the way you want. There are many questions on SO about doing that, see [`[r] scale_x_date`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+scale_x_date).

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I thought having done it with the original dataset  before separating the data by gender with:  `P_cases_reduced$`P_cases$DateResultRelease`<- as.Date(P_cases_reduced$`P_cases$DateResultRelease`, format = c("%d.%m.%y"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the great advice of **@AllanCameron** and **@r2evans** first transform to date in x-axis to date and then use `scale_x_date()`. No output showed due to lack of data:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
plot_cases <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x= Date, y= Count)) +
  xlab("Time") + ylab("Number of Cases") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 2000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%B-%d",breaks = '7 days') +
  geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female,
            aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_female$Sex, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(data = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male,
            aes(colour = P_cases_reduced_aggregated_male$Sex, group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF00FF", "#000FFF"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, as I run your code I get the following error: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: Set `aes(x= as.Date(Date,'%d.%m.%y'), y= Count)` in the first line and test again!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now, I get another error `Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @ValentineDiLello It looks like an issue with x, try only `x=as.Date(Date)`

Comment: Perfect, with only `x=as.Date(Date)` I do not get any errors anymore. However, as before with only `scale_x_discrete()` I do not get any graduation for the x-axis...

Comment: @ValentineDiLello I have added an update, that should allow you to read the labels on x-axis!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help; it is perfectly working!